# How to display content in a JTextArea or ScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I input into a text field "C". What should be displayed should be the next 10 letters that come after C. What I could do is convert all these letters into strings and then set the strings text to a JLabels text, but instead I want to be able to show them on a textArea with a scroll pane so that it doesn't run off the page and instead stays within a window I can scroll down from.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I have a TextArea fitted with a scroll pane setup, but I don't know how to output any data here.

Comment: "I have a TextArea fitted with a scroll pane setup" - use [setText(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) method.  For more help please show your code.

Comment: @c0der I knew it would of been simple. Ty.